# Bluetooth abstract device ping

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have to know RSSI, or at least that device in range for set of devices. There is some devices that invisible by default (Headset, etc.) So i already could relay that all devices already paired, and i have their MAC. As i understand there is just 2 basic connection types. On witch all other profiles are based. So is there any universal "key" to connect to every device type? I tried to fetch all UUID for each device, then try to connect using RFCOM sequentially using each uid. I hope device online if at least one connection is not fired timeout exception. Maybe there is more abstract and simple way? Could i rely that device support and will return uuids using SDP. Does BLE devices support RFCOM connections?

Comment: was not clear about your question. however BLE does not support RFCOMM.

Comment: My question is how to check "is paired device in range or not"

Answer (score 0):

Understood, then for BR/EDR, in case you've already know their address, you may use `getRemoteName` to decide whether they are in range, this command will establish the temp ACL and then disconnect soon after fetched the name. If the error code was page time out, then we assume it is out of range but if we can got the name, then they are in range. You do not check their SDP actually. However for BLE, if they are not advertisement, you may not found them.

Comment: What the class have this method? could you please give me a link to the doc?

Comment: look like find it as a hidden API

Comment: seems yes if you are using Android. if you are using android, you may try to directly connect the SPP(or say RFCOMM channel)

Comment: have just called getRemoteName using reflection, it look like return cached value, in case it works while device offline

Comment: as for SPP, which UUID exist on every device?

Comment: looking to the source code - getName use getRemoteName internaly http://pastebin.com/yy2y1M7L so not a solution

Comment: For Android, yes, basically all android support SPP.

Comment: I need every device not just android

Comment: Then only check the SDP is a right way since all device support SDP.